# Yahoo social/contacts api -> update contact (PUT method)

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

So..   The application I wrote ages ago to update yahoo contacts seems to have quit working... It was using oauth1 to authenticate...

doing a PUT to http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/me/contacts
gets me a `404 Not Found on Accelerator` error

```
<!-- status code : 404 -->
<!-- Not Found on Accelerator -->
<!-- host machine: e20.ycpi.cha.yahoo.com -->
<!-- timestamp: 1506448562.000 -->
<!-- url: http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/me/contacts-->
```

Thinking the issue may be their oauth1 api..   I switched to oauth2

same error

So I try http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/me/contacts  (httpS) 
I get
`401 You are unauthorized for this operation`

I'm using scope `sdct-w` (https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/yahoo_scopes/)

Is Yahoo Contacts API dead or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/{guid}/contacts`

a)  the endpoint is now https  (documentation still shows http)
b)  used to be able to use "me" for the {guid} ... this is no longer the case

Answer (score 1):

You have to add access token on your request.
Try:

```
https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/me/contacts?access_token=${access_token}&format=json
```